# sent file from React to Node and got empty obj

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I am  getting img data and send this data to the server
console.log shows that data exists

```
 const [fileData, setFileData] = useState("");
 console.log("fileData:", fileData);
 const getFile = (e: any) => {
 setFileData(e.target.files[0]);
 };

 const uploadFile = (e: any) => {
e.preventDefault();
const data = new FormData();
data.append("file", fileData);
axios({
  method: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost:5000/api/setImage",
  data: data,
  headers: {
    "content-type": "multipart/form-data", // do not forget this
  },
}).then((res) => {
  alert(res.data.message);
});
};
```

server endpoint

```
router.post("/setImage", userController.setImage);

async setImage(req, res, next) {
try {
  let uploadFile = req.body;
  console.log(uploadFile);
} catch (e) {
  next(e);
}
```

}

console.log shows empty object but I'm waiting img data

Comment: There is a package called [`Multer for Express`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer), you should take a look at it :) I had the same issue recently

Answer (score 1):

Try using [multer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer) with [fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/filestream) and [tempy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tempy).

```
router.post("/setImage", multer({ dest: tempy.file() }).single("file"), async (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.file) return
    fs.readFile(req.file.path, function (err, filedata) {
        if (!req.file) return
        // Here you should get your expected data in filedata variable
    })
})
```